# Get min and max value of an array of strings in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array and it is formatted as string:

```
['identifier','6.35', '2.72', '11.79', '183.25']
```

The first item is always 'identifier' so must be filtered out.

What I need in this example as output is:

```
MaxValue = 183.25
MinValue = 2.72
```

What would be a clean and fast way to achieve this? My arrays can contain a lot of data.

Comment: `Math.min` `Math.max` may be quicker than an Array reduce - but for 4 elements, microseconds won't be an issue

Comment: What did you try to solve this yourself?

Comment: The array is made of strings (and words ?) so are you sure .min & .max would work ?

Comment: `a=['identifier','6.35','2.72','11.79','183.25'],b=a.map(Number).filter($=>!isNaN($)),MinValue=Math.min(...b),MaxValue=Math.max(...b)`

Comment: Is that a question for clarification, Bravo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to start by filtering out anything that is not numeric. You can then find the min and max as an aggregation. You could also optimize this by checking for a numeric during the aggregation to save scanning over the array once upfront):

```js
const input = ['identifier','6.35', '2.72', '11.79', '183.25']

const result = input.filter( x => !isNaN(x)).reduce( (acc, x) => {
 acc.max = Math.max(acc.max,x);
 acc.min = Math.min(acc.min,x); 
 return acc;
}, {min: Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY, max: Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY})

console.log(result);
```

Or if you prefer you can pass the resulting array to the `Math.min` and `Math.max` functions

```js
const input = ['identifier','6.35', '2.72', '11.79', '183.25']

const nums = input.filter( x => !isNaN(x));

console.log(Math.max(...nums));
console.log(Math.min(...nums));
```

Comment: This works great. One additional question. Is it possible to have the min value be the first number above 0?

Comment: let nums = parentstockGraphData.graphlegperc[0].filter( x => !isNaN(x) );
                nums = nums.filter( x => x!=0)
                alert(Math.max(...nums));
                alert(Math.min(...nums));

Answer (score 0):

Scan the array only once

```js
let data = ["identifier", "6.35", "2.72", "11.79", "183.25"];

function minMax(data) {
  let min = Infinity;
  let max = -Infinity;

  for (let s of data) {
    let n = Number.parseFloat(s);
    if (Number.isNaN(n)) continue;
    if (min > n) min = n;
    if (max < n) max = n;
  }
  return [min, max];
}

console.log(minMax(data));
```